# How to run mysqldump command in java code?

Tags: java, unit-testing, eclipse-rcp, mysql

I want to test to run mysqldump command in my function but I could not create aaadumpdb.sql file. My code is below:

```
@Test
public void dumpDB() {
    Process p = null;
    try {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        p = runtime
                .exec("mysqldump -u root -padmin --add-drop-database aaa_db "
                        + "D:\\backupdenemeaaa " + "aaadumpdb.sql");
        // change the dbpass and dbname with your dbpass and dbname
        int processComplete = p.waitFor();

        if (processComplete == 0) {

            System.out.println("Backup created successfully!");

        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JDialog(),
                    "Could not create the backup");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    File f = new File("aaadumpdb.sql");

    assertTrue(f.exists());
}
```

Can anybody give me some advice about it? Thank you.

I did some edit in my code but when I run, my code enter into else structure. What can be the problem?

My editted code is below:

```
    @Test
public void dumpDB() {
    Process p = null;
    try {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        String mysqldumpExecutable = "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.6\\bin\\mysqldump.exe";
        p = runtime.exec(mysqldumpExecutable + " -uroot -padmin --add-drop-database -B aaa_db -r" + "D:\\backupdenemeaaa " + "\\aaadumpdb.sql");
        // change the dbpass and dbname with your dbpass and dbname
        int processComplete = p.waitFor();

        if (processComplete == 0) {

            System.out.println("Backup created successfully!");

        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JDialog(),
                    "Could not create the backup");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    File f = new File("aaadumpdb.sql");

    assertTrue(f.exists());
```

How can I solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: That is because you are not handling the output streams of Process object soon after you are initializing it.
You need to handle Process's getErrorStream and getOutputStream so that  you will ocme to know if any exception persists in the command you wish to execute.

Lastly, is MySql's bin located in your path variable?
How is JVM suppose to know where mysqldump command is !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stacktrace would really help to debug it, but I believe you can check if "mysqldump" is in your PATH or the application will simple not find the executable. If you don't want to mess around with your PATH you can hardcode the path to the executable like below:

```
String mysqldumpExecutable = "C:\\apps\\mysql\\mysqldump.exe";
runtime.exec(mysqldumpExecutable + "-u root -padmin --add-drop-database aaa_db (.....));
```

When you say you can't create the file what exactly does that mean? Are you getting an error? Nothing happens? Help us help you.

Comment: I take an error for command line: "p = runtime.exec("mysqldump -u root -padmin --add-drop-database aaa_db " + "D:\\backupdenemeaaa " + "aaadumpdb.sql");" The error is : "java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mysqldump": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: OK that was a simple path problem and I see you have now hardcoded the mysqldump path into your code. Checking the javadoc for Process.waitFor() it says that when it returns 0 it means the application ran smoothly and finished all right, it returns something else when something goes wrong. It means that mysqldump is called from you app but results in error. I recommend you to check the parameters you're using to call mysqldump. It's not a Java issue anymore. Tip: try running mysqldump from prompt first and then adequate your code.

Comment: I checked mysqldump command and fixed the bug. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below snippet to find what exactly is happening

```
try
        {
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr,4094);
            String line=null;
            while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(type + "> " + line);    
            } catch (IOException ioe)
              {
                ioe.printStackTrace();  
              }
    }
```

You will be aware of the the exceptions and errors that might occur in that Process execution